# NextJS/NestJS authentication flow issue after deployement to Vercel

Tags: authentication, next.js, cookies, nestjs, vercel

I'm facing an issue with my NextJS/NestJS authentication flow
I'm using NextJS middleware to intercept authentication secure cookies and manage secure routes in Im NextJS frontend, the secure cookies are generated in a different server using NestJS
MY middleware source code:

```
 import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import cookie from 'cookie';
import { decodeJwtToken } from './utils/decodejwttoken';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
 const authRoutes = ['/signin', '/signup'];
 const cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.get('Cookie') || '');
 const tokenFromHeaders = cookies.token;
 const tokenObj = request.cookies.get('token');
 const tokenFromCookies = tokenObj?.value;
 console.log({ tokenFromCookies, tokenFromHeaders });
...
```

In local development, it's working correctly, but after deployment to Vercel I'm getting tokenFromCookies and tokenFromHeaders undefined
Any help will be appreciated, thanks